# Solving $ \frac {dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y} x\cos(x) $ with $y(0) = 1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was helping someone work this problem out for an online course and I thought it'd be pretty easy since it's a first order separable DE. I ended up with

$$ y = \frac {(x\sin(x) + \cos(x) + 1)^2}{4}    $$

and when I plug this answer back into the original DE, it works out, yet the
online system doesn't accept it! Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: If you're plugging it into the original DE and getting that it works out, chances are your constant is off (i.e. the "$+1$" is wrong) since the derivatives would be the same.

Comment: @Brenton, you can tell by inspection that it satisfies $y(0)=1$.

Comment: @vadim123 I didn't check, but WA shows it should be $-3$ instead of $+1$

Comment: I get that the solution _does_ satisfy the diff. eq.

Comment: $$y' = \frac{1}{4}\left(2(x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+1)(\sin(x) + x\cos(x) - \sin(x))\right) = \frac{1}{2}(x\sin(x) + x\cos(x)-\sin(x)(x\cos(x)))$$.  The only issue _may_ be that $\sqrt{y} \neq \frac{x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+1}{2}$ but I believe that $x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+1 \geq 0$ so that assertion should be correct...*EDIT*: this assertion is not correct.

Comment: @Jared, also if we replace $1$ by $-3$, then $y(0)=1$ still but now $x\sin(x)+\cos(x)-3$ is negative.  So Alpha appears to be wrong here.

Comment: @vadim123 I would have to defer to someone more knowledgeable but it seems to me that $\sqrt{y} \neq \frac{x\sin(x)+\cos(x)-3}{2}$ at $x = 0$ while the OP's solution _is_ valid when $x = 0$.

Comment: Presumably you've gotten to the step that:

$$
2\sqrt{y} = x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+C
$$

Plug in $x = 0$ and $y = 1$ to find $C$:

$$
2 = 1 + C \rightarrow C = 1
$$

I don't see how $C = -3$ can be a valid solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It seems the answer is only valid within inter $(-\pi, \pi)$, beyond that interval, y is negative and $\sqrt y$ is not valid.